# Open firebug inscpector using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

From a bookmarklet I need to open firebug and inspecting an element.

I know firebug got a command "inspect" but it seems it's not possible to execute this command from javascript.

Firebug can be driven using the new firefox command line ...but it seems we can not execute command line from javascript.

If you have an idea?

---

I have a bookmarklet which finds errors in the HTML code. The bookmarklet lists all elements in error. If user clicks on an element, I would like to display it in firebug inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here. If you are trying to debug your own code then use javascript "debugger" command to cause firebug to break on a given line of code.

If you are looking to trigger Firebug to open at an end user's browser then this would cause confusion for the user and also this option could possibly be a security risk.

Anyway if firebug is deactivated then it can't respond to anything so you wouldn't be able to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I want to trigger Firebug to inspect an element in the page. It's not possible but, as you said, maybe it could be a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You can open FireBug just by pressing F12 in the browser

Comment: I have a bookmarklet which finds errors in the HTML code. The bookmarklet lists all elements in error. If user clicks on an element, I would like to display it in firebug inspector.